# How to include padding for bootstrap 3 nav-tabs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, padding, nav

In my view, I'm having a bootstrap nav-tabs and i want to include a padding to the dropdown I've created which is in thr nav-tabs.

```
<ul class="page-title__nav common-list nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: -5px;width: 700px;">
  <li class="dropdown active" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Inventory<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px">
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadCategories()">Categories</a></li><br>
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadItems()">Items</a></li><br>
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadModifierGroups()">Modifier Groups</a></li><br>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadTenders()">Orders</a></li>
</ul>
```

But the style is not applied for the Inventory tab with dropdown. What could be gone wrong here?

The view:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap nav-tabs there are defined padding. If you want to customize the padding better to override it by applying !important to your style.

```
padding-right: 40px !important;
padding: 40px 30px 10px 20px !important;
```

Hope this help.